# Get InnerHTML of Class within a Given DIV

Tags: jquery, innerhtml

Need to get the data from a class called "one_price" within a DIV called "Main"

**In the HTML below I need to return (£2.50) from the code**

I have tried the $('main').find('.one_price') but can not seem to get the value inside the class from this approach any ideas

```
<div id="main">         
<div class="product-column one-column right_col">
<div class="product-box">
<div class="product-box-section">
<span class="product_price">
<span class="product_price_values">
<span class="price_title one_price_title">Price: </span>
<span class="one_price">&pound;2.50</span>

                        <span id="product_rrp">
                            Was <span class="strikethrough">&pound;7.00</span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <span id="product_saving">
                            <span id="you_save">
                                <em class="hd">Save</em>
                                <em class="percentage val">64&#37;</em>
                                <em class="currency val">&pound;4.50</em>
                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: You have no element with the `id`, or `class` of `'main'`. What did you *expect* it to match, precisely?

Comment: updated code with DIV ID now

Comment: Thank you, now: "*[Can't use] this as there [are] more than one `.one_price` class [elements] on the page*". Can you give a more inclusive excerpt of your DOM? To show us what it looks like? And what specific result you want to obtain?

Comment: And why on earth would I follow an obfuscated URL? You have six-hundred characters to play with in comments: feel free to use them all, they're free! And *you* need to reduce the HTML of that page to a [Minimal, Complete, Verified Excample code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) and post that code *here*, otherwise this question is useless to others in the future.

Comment: var price = $('#main').find('.one_price').text(); worked I messed up the console.log.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your posted HTML is wrapped in a `<div>` with the `id` of 'main' then the following *will* work (in most browsers, though tested only in Chrome 37/Windows 8.1):

```
var price = $(main).find('.one_price').text();
console.log(price);
```

```js
var price = $(main).find('.one_price').text();

console.log(price);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="product-column one-column right_col">
    <div class="product-box">
      <div class="product-box-section">
        <span class="product_price">
<span class="product_price_values">
<span class="price_title one_price_title">Price: </span>
        <span class="one_price">&pound;2.50</span>

        <span id="product_rrp">
                            Was <span class="strikethrough">&pound;7.00</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span id="product_saving">
                            <span id="you_save">
                                <em class="hd">Save</em>
                                <em class="percentage val">64&#37;</em>
                                <em class="currency val">&pound;4.50</em>
                            </span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This works *only* because an element with an `id` is automatically (for legacy, I believe IE, compatibility) wherein it was considered a convenience. This is *not* recommended however, and should be:

```
var price = $('#main').find('.one_price').text();
console.log(price);
```

```js
var price = $('#main').find('.one_price').text();

console.log(price);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="product-column one-column right_col">
    <div class="product-box">
      <div class="product-box-section">
        <span class="product_price">
<span class="product_price_values">
<span class="price_title one_price_title">Price: </span>
        <span class="one_price">&pound;2.50</span>

        <span id="product_rrp">
                            Was <span class="strikethrough">&pound;7.00</span>
        </span>
        </span>
        <span id="product_saving">
                            <span id="you_save">
                                <em class="hd">Save</em>
                                <em class="percentage val">64&#37;</em>
                                <em class="currency val">&pound;4.50</em>
                            </span>
        </span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: var price = $(main).find('.one_price').text() returns undefined on page

Comment: As well it should (though, as noted, it works for me using Chrome), it's a legacy 'feature' that allowed for things to break unexpectedly. Now, using it properly, what does `$('#main').find('.one_price').text()` give you?

Comment: @Stephan: thanks! But do note that it's a horrible, *horrible* 'feature' (note the scare-quotes), and any automagical (and *global*) variable can be overwritten so very, very easily.

Comment: $('#main').find('.one_price').text() is undefined aswell

Comment: Then you have a problem in your page that you haven't bothered to communicate, or your HTML is inadequately representative of your actual HTML/DOM.

Comment: That went without saying,  just fun to explore the quirks and oddnesses of browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `$(yourSelector).text();` to select the text contents of an element. Also, you don't need `find()`, you can just string the selectors like you would in CSS:

See this example:

```js
alert( $('#main .one_price').text() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <div class="product-box-section">
        <span class="product_price">
            <span class="product_price_values">
                <span class="price_title one_price_title">Price: </span>
                <span class="one_price">&pound;2.50</span>

                <span id="product_rrp">
                Was <span class="strikethrough">&pound;7.00</span>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span id="product_saving">
                <span id="you_save">
                    <em class="hd">Save</em>
                    <em class="percentage val">64&#37;</em>
                    <em class="currency val">&pound;4.50</em>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see you edited your example to include `id="main"`, I'll update my selector, although the gist of the answer remains the same.

Comment: Cant Use this as there more than one "one_price" class on the page

Answer (score 0):

If you seek to view only one result you must add more selectors to the html (add more "id-class"s) to the html. If else can you please explain what you want, exactly?